# Data from db isn't returned but normal list is

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, lazy-loading

I'm building a webapi and I have strange problem.

When I do something like this

```
List<Content> items = new List<Content>();
```

And than i add items to it

```
items.Add(new Content());
```

And than I invoke url localhost/api/Content/Get I'll get a nice xml with my items
But when I do something like this

```
public IEnumerable<Content> Get()
{
    List<Content> population = new List<Content>();
    Content[] test = new Content[5];

    var tmp = from c in db.Content select c;
    using (IEnumerator<Content> enumerator = tmp.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            Content ctmp = (Content)enumerator.Current;
            population.Add(ctmp);
        }
    }
    return population;
}
```

And I invoke same url I get blank (white) page. Same think when I'll return the tmp variable.

**Update:**

thanks for help. Main question is still standing. Why normal List is returned correctly and List created from db isn`t. Making a copy from DataProxies.Content to COntent isn't the solution that I've dreamed off and as Jon noticed it's a bit odd.

None of samples with `db.Content.ToList()` helped :/ I'm confuesed

Comment: If you are still hunting for reasons why this is not behaving as expected, I have a blog post here that shows one way to debug Web API serialization issues. http://www.bizcoder.com/index.php/2012/08/10/troubleshooting-serialization-problems-in-web-api/

Comment: I found a solution by disabling proxy entetie. You think its ok? I've posted it in my answer below

Comment: I don't really know, that's a EF / DataContractSerializer question really and I don't use those technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. At least I think I did

I use

```
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Than I get normal objects not proxy dynamic entities

About your question Jon. How am I exposing that method ? There is not much to tell. I`ve created ApiController from template and just edited the method

```
    public class ContentController : ApiController
{
    private signsEntities db = new signsEntities();

    // GET api/content
    public IEnumerable<Content> Get()
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Content[] test = this.db.Content.ToArray<Content>();
        return test;
    }
}
```

This is whole class. Not much as you can see :)

Answer (score 2):

Presumably your SQL query doesn't find any items, so the list returned from the method is empty. Note that your code can be expressed much more simply as:

```
public IEnumerable<Content> Get()
{
    return db.Content.ToList();
}
```

or possibly:

```
public IEnumerable<Content> Get()
{
    return db.Content.Cast<Content>().ToList();
}
```

You'd need to explain a bit more about `db.Content` for us to help you more. Perhaps you should be creating a new database context? For example:

```
public IEnumerable<Content> Get()
{
    using (FooDataContext db = new FooDataContext())
    {
        return db.Content.ToList();
    }
}
```

EDIT: If you *really* want to make sure you're just returning `Content` objects, not the dynamic proxies, you could write something like:

```
public IEnumerable<Content> Get()
{
    using (FooDataContext db = new FooDataContext())
    {
        return db.Content
                 .ToList()
                 .Select(c => new Content { Name = c.Name,
                                            Foo =  c.Foo,
                                            // etc
                         });
    }
}
```

... just copying the properties directly.

Comment: I`ve debuged the variable tmp and the query that is there is correct. It gets all items from db. I also debuged the list that I generate in lopp and it has items but not type Content but some kind of System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxy.Content. Beside that your first and second sample gives same result. Blnka page and list of this strange type

Comment: @Fixus: That dynamic proxy presumably extends the *real* `Content` type. But if the list returned from the method contains data, then the problem must be in whatever's using it.

Comment: I don`t get it ? Cause nothing is using it. For example I use your sample return db.Content.Cast.... than I invoke the url and I got blank page. Strangly I can't cast from DynamiProxies.Content to normal Content in loop (p.s. Third sample has same result :( )

Comment: @Fixus: What do you mean by "I can't cast ... in loop"? What happens?

Comment: Thats the problem that nothing happens. I get a List of DataProxies.Content. Content ctmp = (Content)enumerator.Current;
            population.Add(ctmp);
After that I still got DataProxies.Content in population list

Comment: @Fixus: Yes, you would. Casting doesn't change the actual type of an object, unless you're invoking an overloaded operator.

Comment: ok good to know :) But still main question stands. Why normal List<Content> is returned correctly and List<Content> created from db isn`t ?

Comment: @Fixus: See my edit for something you might want to try, but it's a bit odd if you need to do this...

Comment: As you said. It`s odd solution. I need to find out why normal approach isn`t working :/

Comment: @Fixus: Well you should try the workaround first, to see whether that *does* work.

Comment: In this workaround I get "The entity or complex type 'SignDictionaryModel.Content' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."

Comment: Ok this workaround works. When I copy elements one by one it works

Comment: But IMO this isn`t correct. If you and abatischev posted same simple 1 line answer IMO this copy stuff isn`t natural

Comment: @Fixus: Well the problem is we don't really know what's consuming this sequence. How the list is produced is irrelevant - it just seems that the consumer can't handle the dynamic proxy, only the "real" `Content` type.

Comment: any solution for that ? Maybe I can provide some usefull info ?

Comment: @Fixus: Well you still haven't told us how you're exposing that method. Something must be calling it, somehow, and we know you're trying to expose a web service... but you haven't told us anything else.

Comment: I`ve added more info in new answer cause I think I found the solution

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = db.Content.ToList();
```

Comment: unfortunatly it didn`t help. More about this in Joh Skeet answer